# How to create first database user account?

Tags: php, mysql, database-administration, user-accounts

Out of curiosity!

If I am starting to create my first webpage with php and mysql. How should I start adding admin user?

Let's say I want to be the admin, all the user who sign up will be checked first by me, but how should I create my own username and password?

Usually, we create temporary username:admin and password:admin, but with this practice, my password is not encrypted, right?  And still `admin`.

Next, I'll create a sign up page where the password will be encrypted before posting to database. With this, their passwords are encrypted (example: `$2a$10$MNG1cfp3pCDdIJFFzvq0nQ`) unlike the admin account which is still 'admin'

Now my question is, what could be the best way to add my first admin account in my database?

I hope you get my point.

**----------EXAMPLE-------------**

Should I register first my admin account so my password is encrypted, and once I registered my account, I will revise the sign up page so no one can register as admin again?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour], and read [ask].  This question is too broad.

Comment: Thanks sir. But I don't know how to expand more my question. I am having hard time expressing some things in English.

Comment: There are too many possible ways to set things up; it seems like you need to research how web sites interact with a database; you do not mention what database you want to use, for just one item.

Comment: There, i revised and the database and language will be using. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: what you really need to do is plan out your website, what it's main goal is. In this case, just a simple log in, with some separation from admin and the everyday joe. This for me, instantly screams making a users table with 4 columns: user_id, username, password, user_type with another table with a foreign key on user_type, and in that table called user_types have cols type_id, type_name which is the fk for user_type

Answer (score 0):

It has many solutions:

**One:**

You can add some sort of an admin page or admin sign up page during installation or first run of the project. Then after setting up the admin details, delete or create a mechanism to disable the page.

**Two:**

Create the an encrypted password by using different online tools like

http://www.sha1-online.com/

And store the generated string.

And other methods you could think of.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was:

I first created a sign up page. Then registered as an admin. After registering my admin account, I created the log in page and user maintenance page. With that, I am the only one allow to register a user.